# How do I disable banners for remote jobs with cups-lpd under systemd?

Tags: systemd, printing, cups, lpd

I'm familiar with how to disable the banners on a system running xinetd (server_args = -o job-sheets=none in /etc/xinetd.d/cups-lpd). I've located the cups-lpd@.service file, which would appear to serve the same purpose, but the parameter names appear to be different, and I haven't been able to track down exactly how to pass the -o ... Is there any documentation for this?

For now, I have run lpoptions -p $printer -o job-sheets=none for each printer, but this seems to be a sub-optimal approach.

Comment: You can disable banners through `http://localhost:631/printers`.

Comment: @waltinator Already done that. The problem is a banner that cups-lpd is adding prior to the cups receiving the job.